# get friends on facebook application 2.1

Tags: facebook

I'll try to get friends name with an application created in facebook. I don't know what is the permission to get it, I did a test using facebook graph api using get method and filling me?fields=id,name,friends, thw results are friends data null but the summary total count says 3.

Comment: You call /me/friends and it will return all friends that are using your app and have granted it user_friends permission

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`/me/friends` is the correct way to get your friends. Keep in mind that you will only get those who authorized your App too, and there is a total_count field that tells you the total amount of friends.

Example code and information: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/user/friends

Comment: I use that but I can see data, the user_friends permission is available,the idea to my project is: I want to get my account's friends. the purpose is create a backup saving my friends

Comment: the simple answer to that is: you can´t do it (anymore). not sure why you would want to do it anyway, because....well, you can´t really restore them on facebook ;)

Comment: I want to create something like this http://www.socialsafe.net/ is a desktop application, It creates a backut facebook, also twitter and other ones. You would think this is possible to do?

Comment: even those platforms will not be able to get all friends after april 2015

Comment: thanks a lot, I wasted time looking for a solution, I used php, java and android app, thanks man